# Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: error when configuring mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, iis, fuelphp

I am trying to configure my db (connection strings below)

```
return array(
'default' => array(
    'connection'  => array(
        'dsn'        => 'mysql:host=Webdatabase; dbname=web_btw',
        'username'   => 'btw_user',
        'password'   => 'pass12',       
    ),
),
);
```

However, I receive the following PHPErrorException notice (in one of my view files):

```
<? if (isset($error)): ?><p class="error-msg"><?= $error ?></p><? endif ?>
```

If possible, I would like to know why it is going to this error message when all I want is to establish db connection to my fuelphp application.

Thank you

Comment: Could you paste the error message into your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions but I have solved the problem by enabling PHP short tags in php.ini to correct the error.